# Undeletable "Icon" file

Tags: command-line, permissions, delete, rm

I have a strange problem with some files on my NAS that are not deletable, maybe remnants of some MacOS file copy.

They appear with filename "Icon" in file manager but as `'Icon'$'\r'` with ls.

Permissions are 755 (but 700 if I check them from MacOS), and I tried to delete them using `rm -f 'Icon'$'\r'` to no avail, resulting in a "No such file or directory" error in terminal.

I tried to use `chattr -i` on them with the same results.

I even tried to delete them from MacOS but didn't work.

I absolutely need to get rid of them but I can't think to anything else, any help from Linux gurus?

Comment: With wildcard `rm Icon*` ?

Comment: Yes, tried that. I tried almost everything with rm, I'm going crazy.

Comment: I'm afraid this is off topic here, since it isn't about Ubuntu, but is on topic on our sister site, [linux.se]. Please delete and repost there, but also include what `rm` commands you have tried and the exact error they gave you. `rm ./Icon*` should work, and so should `rm Icon?` or `find . -name 'Icon*' -delete`.

Comment: I am actually on Ubuntu 20.04.1 so I think this is in topic here. But I will edit original post with all I tried (I receive everytime the same "No such file or directory" error)

Comment: Question, what filesystem is this? When possible, force a filesystem check. When possible, remount the volume with special mount options, which forbid non ASCII characters being used in a filename.

Comment: I managed to delete those files using the file manager on Synology DSM. I usually use terminal for almost everything so I didn't think of it sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when rsync'ing files off my NAS. rsync would occasionally report...

```
file has vanished: "/Volumes/archives/blerg/Icon\#015"
```

Looking at the source, a zero byte `Icon?` file was still present and couldn't be deleted.

```
$ ls -l
-rwx------  1 molomby  staff     0B  4 Sep  2020 Icon?
```

I tried:

```sh
$ rm 'Icon'$'\r'
rm: Icon\r: No such file or directory
$ rm Icon*    
rm: Icon\r: No such file or directory
$ find . -name 'Icon*' -delete
find: -delete: unlink(./Icon\r): No such file or directory
```

No joy.

### A Solution:

In the end I just moved all the *other* files elsewhere and deleted the containing directory. It worked but surely there's a better way.